# Airflow: Module not found

Tags: python, docker-compose, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to schedule a python script in airflow.
When the script start to execute it fails to find specific mysql module.
I already installed mysql-connector.
So it should not be a problem.
Please help me here.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running airflow in a docker image, the python lib you use should be install in the docker image.

For example, if you are using the image `apache/airflow`, you can create a new docker image based on this image, with all the libs you need:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow
RUN pip install mysql-connector
```

Then you build the image:

```bash
docker build -t my_custom_airflow_image <path/to/Dockerfile>
```

Then you can replace `apache/airflow` in your docker-compose file by `my_custom_airflow_image`, and it will work without any problem.